# issue with strcmp() not comparing strings properly

Tags: c++, string, comparison, string-comparison, strcmp

Here's the actual code, since it seems to be specific to something here.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>

using namespace std;

int main()

cout << "  Just say \"Ready\" when you want to start.";
char tempReady[20];
cin >> tempReady;
length = strlen(tempReady);
char* ready = new char[length+1];
strcpy(ready, tempReady);
while((strcmp(ready, "Ready")||strcmp(ready, "ready"))!=0)
   {
   cout << "Try again.";
   cin >> tempReady;
   length = strlen(tempReady);
   delete[] ready;
   ready = new char[length+1];
   strcpy(ready, tempReady);
   }
cout << "Success";
```

Anyone see anything wrong?

Comment: You're not using `std::string`.

Comment: I'm not sure -- your program enters the loop when I try it (under MacOS/X using g++-4.2).  My guess would be that perhaps stdin has included a carriage return or newline character at the end of the string -- do a cout << strlen(string) to see if it is actually 5 chars long or not.

Comment: It worked for me in `gcc` on Linux.

Comment: Your code works for me, the problem must be somewhere in the code you didn't post. Try to post complete programs.

Comment: Your code won't work. You need a few `#include` directives and a `main` function for it to compile.

Comment: You guys are right, this piece of code worked for me too all by itself. Let me look back at the full program and see what's up.

Comment: In my actual program, if i use `strcmp(string, "hello")` and enter "Hello" it will work, and vise versa. It's picky with the first cap. Why? Also, if I add an or in there and do two strcmp()s then it will never return zero.

Comment: To get those questions answered you need to post your actual program. Of course strcmp is not picky with the first cap, it expects all letters to match exactly. Your problems are something else than what you think they are, but without seeing the actual code no-one can help you with them.

Comment: ... it also will return zero if I enter ANYTHING. I have no idea what the hell is going on with this. Here is my new while statement:
`while((strcmp(string, "Hello")||strcmp(string, "hello"))==0)`

Comment: Although you don't know it, you probably entered `"hello\n"` *(with an `[Enter]` at the end of it)*.   Hence, the strings are not exactly equal.

Comment: @user1362548 That while statement is wrong, it should be `while (strcmp(string, "Hello") == 0 || strcmp(string, "hello") == 0)`

Comment: Since the code that you've shared works correctly, we have to assume that the problem is in the code you *haven't* shared. Please reduce your original program to the smallest possible **complete** program that demonstrates the problem (5-10 lines should do). Copy-paste that entire short program into your question. See http://SSCCE.ORG for more info.

Comment: I edited the question to a condensed version of the ORIGINAL program but now my edit disappeared. Why?

Comment: @user1362548 It's unfortunate but sometimes two edits overlap and one of them gets lost. I'd just edit again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
while((strcmp(ready, "Ready")||strcmp(ready, "ready"))!=0)
```

should be

```
while(strcmp(ready, "Ready") != 0 && strcmp(ready, "ready") != 0)
```

The version you wrote will always be true.

Comment: This was the problem all along. All this frustration over a simple logical error. Very obvious.

Answer (score 3):

C-style approach:

```
char str[256];
if (scanf("%255s", str) == 1 && strcmp(str, "hello") == 0) {
    printf("success");
}
```

C++ approach:

```
std::string str;
if (std::cin >> str && str == "hello") {
    std::cout << "success";
}
```

Now decide whether you want to write code in C or C++, just ***don't mix it***.

Comment: And your code doesn't even run into an infinite loop when printing success :)

Comment: @RobertJørgensgaardEngdahl: Yeah, although OP wrote *"I'll enter "hello" at the prompt, and the program will not enter the loop"* ~> which sounds like infinite loop was what he actually aimed for :D

Comment: I didn't notice until I tested it that it was an infinite loop. But at least it infinitely couted success which made success pretty obvious.

Comment: @user1362548: Yes, it's ok. That's why my answer doesn't say anything about that `while`. One more thing: try to avoid using `using namespace std;`, it might make you more troubles. For example you named your array `string`, which might be ambiguous since it can also refer to `std::string` etc.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how to do some basic debugging, such as checking exactly what you input.

```
using namespace std; 

char* string = new char[6];
cin >> string;

for(int i=0; i<6; ++i)
{
    printf("[%d]: Hex: 0x%x;  Char: %c\n", i, string[i], string[i]);
}

while(strcmp(string, "hello")==0)
{
   cout << "success!";
}
```

I suspect that your input is something other than `hello`, (such as `hello\n`, or `hello\r\n`, or maybe even (*unicode*)`hello`, which makes the `strcmp` fail.

But rather than me guessing, you can check for yourself using the simple `printf` above.

If you can come back with the exact Hex dump of your input, and state that `strcmp` ***still*** doesn't work as expected, then we'll have something worth investigating.

Comment: @DanO (Don't I wish.  I've been trying to get people to use debuggers since S.O. started... but most won't even use `printf` "debugging")

Comment: I don't know how to use printf, but I'm inputting directly from the linux terminal and hitting enter once after typing the word. I couted strlen to see that it was exactly 5 chars which tells me enough.

Comment: **WTF** do you mean you don't know how to use `printf`??   I put example code in my answer.  Copy-Paste it into your program.

Comment: (@DanO:  See his comment.  I rest my case. :D )

Comment: @abelenky If only stackoverflow registration could force new users to go through a tutorial on the basics of c. Granted a week long registration process would probably hamper adoptation.